# when server's down, datas on board table disappear in Liferay

Tags: liferay

i'm on 7.2.

i've been making board with configurationPid function of liferay, but it's not working what i think.

here's the thing

I set up three types of board to use preferences function of liferay.

From divCd information of preferences releated with board portlet keys, i can search boards specific datas.

But the problem is that when i shut down the server, datas diappear only for notice board! (divCd - 1 : NOTICE , divCd - 2 : FAQ, divCd -3 : QNA)

This phenomenon only happend to board table.

I didn't notice there's problem in my code because in dev server (local server) i've never seen this before.

This only happen in published server. When published server's down, datas of notice board disappear! (not happend to other table yet. :) ) Blow away for real!

I guess anyone in my company have never seen this (disappearing problem!).

So, because i used configurgationPid function to make reusable board
(Notice board, FAQ board, QNA board), configurationPid is quite suspicious for me. But I couldn't find this trouble shooting cases.

I'm gonna show you all my codes that used for this!

If you know any reasons why board data deleted, Please somebody help me.

Minor helps can alse be helpful for me!

***flow***

1. register board types
   image => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvCck.png)
   Board types can be defined here! and JSP file show theses

***configuration.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Constants"%>
<%@ page import="com.osp.board.constants.OSPBoardWebPortletKeys" %>
<%@ page import="com.osp.board.constants.OSPBoardWebActionKeys" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ include file="../../init.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Board Configuration</title>
</head>
<body>
<liferay-portlet:actionURL portletConfiguration="<%= true %>" var="boardDivActionURL">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="target" value="boardDiv"/>
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
<liferay-portlet:actionURL portletConfiguration="<%= true %>" var="boardActionURL">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="target" value="board"/>
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
<liferay-portlet:actionURL portletConfiguration="<%= true %>" var="boardRemoveURL">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="target" value="boardRemove"/>
    <liferay-portlet:param name="targetedDivCd" value=""/>
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
    <%
        long divCd = Long.parseLong(portletPreferences.getValue("divCd", "0"));
        String originalBoardPlid = portletPreferences.getValue("originalBoardPlid", "");
        boolean mainListYn = Boolean.parseBoolean(portletPreferences.getValue("mainListYn",""));
        String originalBoardPortletName = portletPreferences.getValue("originalBoardPortletName", "");
    %>
    <c:set var="divCd" value="<%= divCd %>"/>
    <c:set var="originalBoardPlid" value="<%= originalBoardPlid %>"/>
    <c:set var="mainListYn" value="<%= mainListYn %>"/>
    <c:set var="originalBoardPortletName" value="<%= originalBoardPortletName %>"/>

    <div class="sheet sheet-lg panel-group panel-group-flush my-5">
        <div class="panel">
            <form action="${boardActionURL}" method="POST">
                <aui:input name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" type="hidden" value="<%= Constants.UPDATE %>" />
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a class="collapse-icon sheet-subtitle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#portletInfoContentBody" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="portletInfoContentBody">
                        Portlet Information
                        <span class="collapse-icon-closed">
                            <svg class="lexicon-icon lexicon-icon-angle-right" focusable="false" role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <path class="lexicon-icon-outline" d="M396.394 255.607c-0.22-6.936-2.973-13.81-8.272-19.111l-227.221-227.221c-11.026-11.059-28.94-11.059-39.999 0-11.058 11.026-11.058 28.941 0 39.999l206.333 206.333c0 0-206.333 206.333-206.333 206.333-11.058 11.058-11.058 28.973 0 39.999 11.059 11.059 28.972 11.059 39.999 0l227.221-227.221c5.3-5.3 8.053-12.175 8.272-19.111z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <span class="collapse-icon-open">
                            <svg class="lexicon-icon lexicon-icon-angle-down" focusable="false" role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <path class="lexicon-icon-outline" d="M256 384c6.936-0.22 13.81-2.973 19.111-8.272l227.221-227.221c11.058-11.026 11.058-28.941 0-39.999-11.026-11.058-28.94-11.058-39.999 0l-206.333 206.333c0 0-206.333-206.333-206.333-206.333-11.059-11.058-28.973-11.058-39.999 0-11.059 11.058-11.059 28.972 0 39.999l227.221 227.221c5.3 5.3 12.174 8.053 19.111 8.272z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                
                <div id="portletInfoContentBody" class="panel-body collapse show">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        PortletKey : ${portletKey}
                        <br/>
                        Plid : ${plid}
                    </div>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${empty boardDivs}">
                            <aui:select name="divSort" label="board-config-property-name-divsort" helpMessage="board-config-property-explain-divsort" disabled="true">
                            </aui:select>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <aui:select name="preferences--divCd--" label="board-config-property-name-divsort" helpMessage="board-config-property-explain-divsort">
                                <option value="0"> </option>
                                <c:forEach items="${boardDivs}" var="boardDiv">
                                    <c:if test="${boardDiv.divCd eq divCd}">
                                        <option value="${boardDiv.divCd}" selected="selected">${boardDiv.divName}</option>
                                    </c:if>
                                    <c:if test="${boardDiv.divCd ne divCd}">
                                        <option value="${boardDiv.divCd}">${boardDiv.divName}</option>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </aui:select>
                             
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="<portlet:namespace/>preferences--mainListYn--" id="<portlet:namespace/>preferences--mainListYn--" value="${mainListYn}"/>
                            <input class="toggle-switch" type="checkbox" id="mainListYn" ${mainListYn ? 'checked="true"' : ''}>
                            <span class="toggle-switch-label">
                                <liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-name-mainlistyn"/>
                                <liferay-ui:icon-help message="board-config-property-explain-mainlistyn"/>
                            </span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="toggle-switch-bar">
                                <span class="toggle-switch-handle" data-label-off="no" data-label-on="yes">
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <aui:input name="preferences--originalBoardPortletName--" label="board-config-property-name-originalboard-portletname" helpMessage="board-config-property-explain-portletname" value="${originalBoardPortletName}">
                    </aui:input>
                        
                    <aui:input name="preferences--originalBoardPlid--" label="board-config-property-name-originalboard-plid" helpMessage="board-config-property-explain-plid" value="${originalBoardPlid}">
                    </aui:input>
                    
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><liferay-ui:message key="save"/></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sheet sheet-lg panel-group panel-group-flush my-5">
        <div class="panel">
            <form action="${boardDivActionURL}" method="POST" id="boardTypeList">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a class="collapse-icon sheet-subtitle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#boardDivContentBody" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="boardDivContentBody">
                        <liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-boarddiv-title"/>
                        <span class="collapse-icon-closed">
                            <svg class="lexicon-icon lexicon-icon-angle-right" focusable="false" role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <path class="lexicon-icon-outline" d="M396.394 255.607c-0.22-6.936-2.973-13.81-8.272-19.111l-227.221-227.221c-11.026-11.059-28.94-11.059-39.999 0-11.058 11.026-11.058 28.941 0 39.999l206.333 206.333c0 0-206.333 206.333-206.333 206.333-11.058 11.058-11.058 28.973 0 39.999 11.059 11.059 28.972 11.059 39.999 0l227.221-227.221c5.3-5.3 8.053-12.175 8.272-19.111z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <span class="collapse-icon-open">
                            <svg class="lexicon-icon lexicon-icon-angle-down" focusable="false" role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <path class="lexicon-icon-outline" d="M256 384c6.936-0.22 13.81-2.973 19.111-8.272l227.221-227.221c11.058-11.026 11.058-28.941 0-39.999-11.026-11.058-28.94-11.058-39.999 0l-206.333 206.333c0 0-206.333-206.333-206.333-206.333-11.059-11.058-28.973-11.058-39.999 0-11.059 11.058-11.059 28.972 0 39.999l227.221 227.221c5.3 5.3 12.174 8.053 19.111 8.272z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                
                <div id="boardDivContentBody" class="panel-body collapse show">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="table-responsive-md">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <!-- <colgroup>
                                    <col width="5%">
                                    <col width="16.5%">
                                    <col width="25.5%">
                                    <col width="10%">
                                    <col width="23%">
                                    <col width="6%">
                                    <col width="8%">
                                </colgroup> -->
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center"><liferay-ui:message key="table-index"/></th>
                                        <c:forEach items="${locales}" var="locale">
                                            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Title(${locale})</th>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center"><liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-boarddiv-column-content"/></th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center"><liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-boarddiv-column-name"/></th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center"><liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-boarddiv-column-fileuse"/></th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center"><liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-boarddiv-column-popupuse"/></th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center"><liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-boarddiv-column-replyuse"/></th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody data-entity="boardDiv">
                                    <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${empty boardDivs}">
                                            <tr data-nodata="true">
                                                <td class="text-center text-danger" colspan="8">
                                                    <liferay-ui:message key="board-config-property-boarddiv-result-noboarddiv"/>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                            <c:forEach items="${boardDivs}" var="boardDiv" varStatus="vs">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="<portlet:namespace/>idx" value="${vs.count}"/>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="<portlet:namespace/>divCd" value="${boardDiv.divCd}"/>
                                                    <td scope="col" class="text-center">${vs.count}</td>
                                                    <c:forEach items="${locales}" var="locale">
                                                        <c:set var="titleKey" value="title_${locale}"/>
                                                        <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>title_${locale}_${vs.count}" value="${boardDiv[titleKey]}" maxlength="30"/>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </c:forEach>
                                                    <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>content_${vs.count}" value="${boardDiv.content}" maxlength="30"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>divName_${vs.count}" value="${boardDiv.divName}" maxlength="30"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>fileUploadUseYn_${vs.count}" ${boardDiv.fileUploadUseYn ? 'checked="true"' : ''}/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>popupYn_${vs.count}" ${boardDiv.popupYn ? 'checked="true"' : ''}/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>replyYn_${vs.count}" ${boardDiv.replyYn ? 'checked="true"' : ''}/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-target-entity="remove" data-event="remove" data-div-cd="${boardDiv.divCd}">
                                                            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-target-entity="boardDiv">
                            <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                            Board Type
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><liferay-ui:message key="save"/></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#mainListYn').on('change', function(){
            $('#<portlet:namespace/>preferences--mainListYn--').val($(this).prop('checked'));
        });
        
        $(document).on('click','[data-target-entity]', function(){
            var target = $('[data-entity="'+$(this).data('targetEntity')+'"]');
            if($(target).find('[data-nodata="true"]').length > 0){
                $(target).empty();
            }
            
            var targetType = $(this).data("targetEntity") || "";
            if(targetType == "remove"){
                var targetedDivCd = $(this).data('divCd') || '';
                if(targetedDivCd != ""){
                    $.ospConfirm({
                        modalDialogClass : 'modal-md',
                        title : '<liferay-ui:message key="board-app-delete-modal-title"/>',
                        confirmText : '<liferay-ui:message key="board-app-notice-delete-modal-btn"/>',
                        body : '<liferay-ui:message key="board-app-delete-modal-body"/>',
                        closeText : '<liferay-ui:message key="board-app-delete-cancel"/>',
                        onSubmit : function(result){
                            if(result){
                                var actionURL = "${boardRemoveURL}";
                                actionURL +="&_com_liferay_portlet_configuration_web_portlet_PortletConfigurationPortlet_targetedDivCd=" + targetedDivCd;
                                window.location = actionURL.toString();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                }
                return;
            }
        
            var idx = $(target).find('tr').length + 1;
            if('content' in document.createElement('template')){
                var tmpl = document.querySelector('#boardDivTmpl');
                var clone = document.importNode(tmpl.content, true);
                $(clone).find("tr").prepend(
                                $('<input/>').attr({
                                    type : 'hidden',
                                    name : '<portlet:namespace/>idx',
                                    value : idx
                                }),
                                $('<input/>').attr({
                                    type : 'hidden',
                                    name : '<portlet:namespace/>divCd',
                                    value : 0
                                })
                            );
                var tds = clone.querySelectorAll("td");
                tds.forEach( (td, i) => {
                    if(i == 0){
                        $(td).text(idx);
                    }else{
                        if($(tds).eq(i).find('input').length > 0){
                            var input = $(td).find('input:eq(0)');
                            var bName = $(input).attr('name');
                            var aName = bName.replace('_idx', '_'+idx);
                            
                            $(tds).eq(i).find('input:eq(0)').attr('name', aName);
                        }
                    }
                });
                
                $(target).append(clone);
            } else{ 
                var input = $('<input/>').addClass('form-control'),
                    checkbox = $('<input/>').attr('type', 'checkbox'),
                    appendTd = $('<td/>').addClass('text-center');
                
                $('<tr/>').append(
                            $('<input/>').attr({
                                type : 'hidden',
                                name : '<portlet:namespace/>idx',
                                value : idx
                            }),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .text(idx),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .append(
                                        $(input).clone().attr('name', '<portlet:namespace/>title_ko_KR_'+idx)
                                    ),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .append(
                                        $(input).clone().attr('name', '<portlet:namespace/>title_en_US_'+idx)
                                    ),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .append(
                                        $(input).clone().attr('name', '<portlet:namespace/>content_'+idx)
                                    ),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .append(
                                        $(input).clone().attr('name', '<portlet:namespace/>divName_'+idx)
                                    ),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .append(
                                        $(checkbox).clone().attr('name', '<portlet:namespace/>fileUploadUseYn_'+idx)
                                    ),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .append(
                                        $(checkbox).clone().attr('name', '<portlet:namespace/>popupYn_'+idx)
                                    ),
                            $(appendTd).clone()
                                    .append(
                                        $(checkbox).clone().attr('name', '<portlet:namespace/>replyYn_'+idx)
                                    )
                    ).appendTo(target);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<template id="boardDivTmpl">
    <tr>
        <td scope="col" class="text-center"></td>
        <c:forEach items="${locales}" var="locale">
            <td scope="col" class="text-center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>title_${locale}_idx"/>
            </td>
        </c:forEach>
        <td scope="col" class="text-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>content_idx"/>
        </td>
        <td scope="col" class="text-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>divName_idx"/>
        </td>
        <td scope="col" class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>fileUploadUseYn_idx"/>
        </td>
        <td scope="col" class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>popupYn_idx"/>
        </td>
        <td scope="col" class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>replyYn_idx"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-target-entity="remove">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

2. If you save for delete, you can see if they exists on my table!

image => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ukWF.png)

3. but, It was not simple if i need to use OSP_BoardDiv.
   In main page, I must know exact plid to get to the right board type.
   For this, I should set plid, divCd before you main page for preview of
   notice board. And i set it on html tags.

image => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaFrU.png)

4. If board types are set, i can read information from BoardRender.
   And the next thing is all the same. Controlling data with action,
   render, resources ... but i can't find any problem on my codes!

   I must get plId infos to nevigate user to get to the right board. So, I access to xml datas of the PortletPreferences table. If portletId is same with board portlet and divCd is same, get datas!
   ***BoardRender.java***

```
package com.osp.board.web.board.command;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PortletPreferences;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCRenderCommand;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionMessages;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.ThemeDisplay;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.LocaleUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
import com.osp.board.constants.ConstantsPagePath;
import com.osp.board.constants.OSPBoardWebPortletKeys;
import com.osp.board.model.Board;
import com.osp.board.model.BoardDiv;
import com.osp.board.service.BoardDivLocalServiceUtil;
import com.osp.board.service.BoardLocalServiceUtil;
import com.osp.constants.CustomRoleConstants;
import com.osp.constants.MessageConstants;
import com.osp.constants.SiteNameConstants;
import com.osp.search.constants.OSPSearchPortletKeys;
import com.osp.util.CustomUtil;
import com.osp.util.OSPPropertiesUtil;
import com.osp.util.OSPUsersUtil;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
            "javax.portlet.name=" + OSPBoardWebPortletKeys.BOARD_PORTLET_KEY,
            "mvc.command.name=/",
            "javax.portlet.version=3.0"
        },
        service = MVCRenderCommand.class
)
public class BoardRender implements MVCRenderCommand {
    
    private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(BoardRender.class);
    @Override
    public String render(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws PortletException {
        
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        String isMainPage = renderRequest.getPreferences().getValue("mainListYn", "false");
        String jspPage = ConstantsPagePath.OSP_BOARD_LIST;
        String escapeTag = "<(/)?([a-zA-Z]*)(\\\\s[a-zA-Z]*=[^>]*)?(\\\\s)*(/)?>";
        long divCd = Long.parseLong(renderRequest.getPreferences().getValue("divCd", "0"));
        try {
            if(divCd > 0) {
                BoardDiv boardDiv = BoardDivLocalServiceUtil.getBoardDiv(divCd);
                Map<String, Object> boardDivMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                boardDivMap.put("title", boardDiv.getTitle(themeDisplay.getLanguageId()));
                // permission check start.
                String divName = GetterUtil.getString(boardDiv.getDivName(), "FAQ").toUpperCase();
                boolean permission = false;
                if(isMainPage.equals("true")) {// write only portal, site admins.
                    List<PortletPreferences> searchPreferences = null;
                    String searchNamespace = "";
                    String siteName = CustomUtil.strNull(OSPPropertiesUtil.getPortalSiteName(),"1");
                    renderRequest.setAttribute("siteName", siteName);
                    if(siteName.equals(SiteNameConstants.BIO)) {
                        searchPreferences = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPortletPreferences().stream().filter(pp -> pp.getPortletId().equals(OSPSearchPortletKeys.TOTAL_LIST_SEARCH_PORTLET_KEY)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        searchNamespace = PortalUtil.getPortletNamespace(OSPSearchPortletKeys.TOTAL_LIST_SEARCH_PORTLET_KEY);
                    }else {
                        searchPreferences = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPortletPreferences().stream().filter(pp -> pp.getPortletId().equals(OSPSearchPortletKeys.MATERIAL_LIST_SEARCH_PORTLET_KEY)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        searchNamespace = PortalUtil.getPortletNamespace(OSPSearchPortletKeys.MATERIAL_LIST_SEARCH_PORTLET_KEY);
                    }
                    if(searchPreferences != null) {
                        long searchPlid = searchPreferences.get(0).getPlid();
                        renderRequest.setAttribute("searchPlid", searchPlid);
                        renderRequest.setAttribute("searchNamespace", searchNamespace);
                    }
                    List<PortletPreferences> boardPrefereneces = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPortletPreferences().stream().filter(pp -> pp.getPortletId().equals(OSPBoardWebPortletKeys.BOARD_PORTLET_KEY)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();
                    List<BoardDiv> boardTypeList = BoardDivLocalServiceUtil.getBoardDivListWithBoardName();
                    for(PortletPreferences pp : boardPrefereneces) {
                        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        InputSource is = new InputSource();
                        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(pp.getPreferences()));
                        Document document = docBuilder.parse(is);
                        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                        if(document.getElementsByTagName("value").getLength() > 0 ) {
                            NodeList valueList = document.getElementsByTagName("value");
                            String nodeValue = "";
                            for(BoardDiv bdiv : boardTypeList) {
                                for(int i = 0; valueList.getLength() > i; i++) {
                                    Node valueNode = valueList.item(i);
                                    nodeValue = valueNode.getTextContent();
                                    if(String.valueOf(bdiv.getDivCd()).equals(nodeValue)) {
                                        Map <String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                                        dataMap.put("plid",pp.getPlid());
                                        dataMap.put("portletId",pp.getPortletId());
                                        dataMap.put("divCd", nodeValue);
                                        resultMap.put(bdiv.getContent().toUpperCase(), dataMap);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                    
                    List<Board> boardListForMainNotice = new ArrayList<Board>();
                    List<Board> boardListForMainFaq = new ArrayList<Board>();
                    for(BoardDiv bdiv : boardTypeList) {
                        if("NOTICE".equals(bdiv.getContent().toUpperCase())) // notice
                            boardListForMainNotice = BoardLocalServiceUtil.getBoardListByDivcdSiteGroupIdsForMain(bdiv.getDivCd(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 0, 3, themeDisplay.getLanguageId());
                        if("FAQ".equals(bdiv.getContent().toUpperCase())) // faq
                            boardListForMainFaq = BoardLocalServiceUtil.getBoardListByDivcdSiteGroupIdsForMain(bdiv.getDivCd(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 0, 4, themeDisplay.getLanguageId());
                    }
                    for(Board board : boardListForMainNotice) {
                        board.setTitle(board.getTitle(LocaleUtil.KOREA));
                        board.setCreateDate(board.getCreateDate());
                        board.setContent(board.getContent(LocaleUtil.KOREA).replaceAll(escapeTag, ""));
                    }
                    for(Board board : boardListForMainFaq){
                        board.setTitle(board.getTitle(LocaleUtil.KOREA));
                        board.setCreateDate(board.getCreateDate());
                        board.setContent(board.getContent(LocaleUtil.KOREA).replaceAll(escapeTag, "").replaceAll("&nbsp;", "<br>").replaceAll("<br>", ""));
                    }
                    renderRequest.setAttribute("boardInfos", resultMap);
                    renderRequest.setAttribute("boardListForMainNotice", boardListForMainNotice);
                    renderRequest.setAttribute("boardListForMainFaq", boardListForMainFaq);
                    jspPage = ConstantsPagePath.OSP_MAIN_BOARD_LIST;
                }else if("QNA".equals(divName)) {// admins or writer.
                    permission = themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker().isSignedIn();
                }else if("FAQ".equals(divName)||divName.equals("NOTICE")) {
                    permission = OSPUsersUtil.isRegularRole(themeDisplay.getUser(), CustomRoleConstants.ADMINISTRATOR);
                    if(!permission) permission = OSPUsersUtil.isSiteRole(themeDisplay.getUser(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), CustomRoleConstants.SITE_ADMINISTRATOR);
                }else {
                    _log.debug("##### DivName '"+divName+"' is not supported yet.");
                    _log.debug("##### Check role like FAQ(Write only admins.).");
                    
                    permission = OSPUsersUtil.isRegularRole(themeDisplay.getUser(), CustomRoleConstants.ADMINISTRATOR);
                    if(!permission) permission = OSPUsersUtil.isSiteRole(themeDisplay.getUser(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), CustomRoleConstants.SITE_ADMINISTRATOR);
                }
                renderRequest.setAttribute("permission", permission);
                // permission check end.
                
                renderRequest.setAttribute("boardDiv", boardDivMap);
            }else {
                SessionErrors.add(renderRequest, MessageConstants.SEARCH_ERROR);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.error(e);
            jspPage = ConstantsPagePath.OSP_MAIN_BOARD_LIST;
            renderRequest.setAttribute("permission", false);
            SessionErrors.add(renderRequest, MessageConstants.SEARCH_ERROR);
        }
        
        // session message print.
        String msgType = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "msgType", "");
        if(msgType.equals("error")) {
            SessionErrors.add(renderRequest, ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "ssMsg", ""));
        }else if(!msgType.equals("")) {
            SessionMessages.add(renderRequest, ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "ssMsg", ""));
        }
        
        SessionMessages.add(renderRequest, PortalUtil.getPortletId(renderRequest) + SessionMessages.KEY_SUFFIX_HIDE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return jspPage;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }

}
```

***BoardConfig.java***

```
package com.osp.board.web.board.config;

import com.liferay.portal.configuration.metatype.annotations.ExtendedObjectClassDefinition;
import com.osp.board.constants.OSPBoardWebPortletKeys;

import aQute.bnd.annotation.metatype.Meta;

@ExtendedObjectClassDefinition(
    category = "board",
    scope = ExtendedObjectClassDefinition.Scope.SYSTEM
)
@Meta.OCD(
        id = OSPBoardWebPortletKeys.BOARD_CONFIG_PORTLET_KEY
        )
public interface BoardConfig {
}
```

Comment: Sorry... while I understand a bit about Liferay, I have no clue what you're asking about, what it has to do with (1) configurationPid from the title of your question, and with (2) programming (to make it on-topic for stackoverflow - see [help/on-topic]). Please read [ask], edit your question to make it about programming or find a place to ask instead (https://liferay.dev might be a good place - but only with additional info)

Comment: Sorry! i was all over the place today. i changed my question a couple of minutes ago. If you know anything about this, i'll really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: i updated my post. If you know anything, i'll appreciate your help :)

Comment: You're posting some code here (by far not "minimal", as in [mcve]), and you crosspost the question with different code in Liferay's Questions site [don't crosspost please - here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824). As you start with this question being about configurationPid, you post an _empty_ Meta.OCD (that would link to configurationPid) on _system_ level, but seem to configure a portlet. This is truly confusing and I still have no idea about the problem. Sorry

Comment: At least you've tried for helping me! Really thank you. And i guess this is nothing to do with liferay... I didn't see this! By overworking until now i finally found the reason why data disappear.